# How to use telegram-bot to just read the message from channel?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Yes, I know I can add my bot to channel as admin and then the bot can work brilliantly.

But what I want to do is to add my bot to other channels to parse the data and do some analysis. How could this be achieved provided that I don't own those channels? Any other possible non-bot methods are welcomed to share.

I am currently using 'twx.botapi' from Python to do bot automation.

Comment: At the moment the bots only can be added just as administrators. Maybe you can change telegram source and read channel content as telegram app...!